# Trying to find solution to touchpad & battery status levels & no shutdown in Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, touchpad, battery

Laptop specs: MSI GL 72 GQD with NVidia GTX950M I5 Intel CPU and a Synaptics Touchpad (ACPI/Syn1507/4&2c3c5a70&0 v7.5)

Dual boot with Win 10 (orginal install) and Lubuntu 16.04 LTS.
To install and boot requires the parameters `NO acpi & nomem` added.

It refuses to see the touchpad and the battery level for charge and discharge. And it also refuses to completely shutdown the system when told to do a complete shutdown. It hangs after stopping most processes.

I have done many tries into looking at the boot config and making sure all updates are done and all extra packages that might be important or marginal.  I have also tried to remove the `no acpi` and/or the `no nomem` part on boot up, but this results in a hung bootup in linux completely and it's not a slow boot since I waited over 15 minutes to make sure.

Comment: If you have multiple unrelated problems, separate them in each question

Comment: from what I have been able to trace down they have a high possible being all tied together, but with no more input from others can not go farther